# Can I take out the links one by one and put them in after crawling?

Tags: jquery

I crawled information from a website. After that, I want to put the information into each variable and write it on the screen with ajax. However, each variable may or may not have url, so we put it in an array, but it is output at the same time. Is there any way?
I'm sorry for the awkward English translation.

app.py

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.FF14_quests

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/quest', methods=['GET'])
def show_quest():
    part01_quest = list(db.quest_part01.find({}, {'_id': False}))
    return jsonify({'part01_quest': part01_quest})


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run('0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

script

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    show_quests();
})

function show_quests() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/quest',
        data: {},
        success: function (response) {
            // 전체 리스트
            let part01_quests = response['part01_quest']
            for(let i = 0 ; i < part01_quests.length; i++){
                // 퀘스트 넘버
                let quest_number = part01_quests[i]['quest_number']
                // 퀘스트 명
                let quest_title = part01_quests[i]['quest_title']
                // 퀘스트 url
                let quest_url = part01_quests[i]['quest_url']
                // 퀘스트 시작 레벨
                let quest_lev = part01_quests[i]['quest_lev']
                // 퀘스트 시작 지점
                let quest_start = part01_quests[i]['quest_start']
                // 퀘스트 보상 아이템
                let quest_result_item = []
                for(let y = 0; y < part01_quests[i]['quest_result_item'].length; y++){
                quest_result_item.push(part01_quests[i]['quest_result_item'][y])
                }
                // 퀘스트 보상 아이템 url
                let item_url = []
                for(let z = 0; z < part01_quests[i]['item_url'].length; z++){
                    item_url.push(part01_quests[i]['item_url'][z])
                }

                // html 붙여넣기
                let temp_html = `<tr>
                                    <th scope="row" colspan="1">${quest_number}</th>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <a href="${quest_url}" target="_blank">
                                            ${quest_title}
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td colspan="1">${quest_lev}</td>
                                    <td colspan="1">${quest_start}</td>
                                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                                </tr>`
                // 붙여넣기
                $('.quest_list').append(temp_html)
            }
        }
    });
}
```